# Why we define supermum of empty set to be $-\infty$ contradiction?

Tags: real-analysis

As Terence tao explains we have the following conclusion that if we consider the empty set as subset of the extended reals. We have the following result:

We know that $sup(E) \geq inf(E)$. This would imply that $-\infty \geq +\infty$. This is non-sense based on the ordering on the extended reals. Why do we get this result ? Is there anything preventing us from getting this result ?

[image]

Comment: "We know that sup(E)≥inf(E)"  No.  You *don't* know this and this example shows that isn't true.  It is always true if $E$ is *not* empty.  But it is false if $E$ *is* empty.

Comment: Look *very closely* at the definitions. They mention the elements of the set. This set has no elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the nature of vacuously true statements.

Let $x \in \emptyset$.  There is no such element so anything we say about is vacuously true.  Is $x$ a green dragon?  Yes.  Since there are no $x \in \emptyset$ then every $x\in \emptyset$ (all zero of them) are green dragons.  This is true because there aren't any $x \in \emptyset$ that *aren't* green dragons.

Suppose $r \in$ extended reals and $x\in \emptyset$.  Is $r \le x$?  Yes.  Since there is not $x\in \emptyset$ that is vacuously true.  $r$ is less than or equal to every element in $\emptyset$ because there aren't any elements in the $\emptyset$ were it is *not* true.

So the empty set is bounded above by $r$ and likewise for *any* $r\in$ extended reals that we choose.  So what is the *least* upper bound.  Well, as all extended reals are upper bounds that would be the same thing as asking what is the least extended real.  And clearly that is $-\infty$.

So $\sup \emptyset = -\infty$.

If that's to breezy we have the definition of $\sup \emptyset = s$ is 1) it is an upper bound.  and 2) the is no $r < s$ that is an upper bound.

Well is that true of $-\infty$?

1) if $x \in \emptyset$ then is $x \le -\infty$?  Yes.  That is vacuously true because there is no $x \in \emptyset$?

2) Is there any $r < -\infty$ that is an upper bound of $\emptyset$.  Well, no, there isn't any $r < -\infty$ at all.

Comment: Perfect. That makes so much sense.

Answer (score 4):

Vacuously, any $x$ has $x\geq y$ for all $y\in \varnothing$, so $\sup \varnothing = \inf \mathbb{R} = -\infty$; and $\inf \varnothing = \infty$ analogously.

For the second part, any $x\in E$ has $\inf(E) \leq x \leq \sup(E)$. If such an $x$ actually exists, then we can conclude $\inf(E)\leq \sup(E)$, but there's no such $x$ in the empty set.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality $\sup(E)\ge\inf(E)$ is only true if $E$ is nonempty. Any element  of $[-\infty,\infty]$ is an upper bound for $\emptyset$, so the *least* upper bound is $-\infty$.